# Convert array to variables dynamically and use them as function arguments

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a lot of mysql queries during data procession. As the actual code hardly changes, I would like to encapsulate it using a function. Such a function could be as follows:

```
// input: sql statement, binding parameters and paramter types
private prepared_statement($query, $params, $param_string) {

        // I use this peace of code over and over again

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        if (!$stmt) {//TODO log
            echo "Error in prepared statement";
        }

        // problem
        $stmt->bind_param($param_string, $param1, $param2, ...);
        $stmt->execute();

        // problem
        $stmt->bind_result($);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close(); 
        //...  
    }
```

The second function argument is an array that contains all binding parameters of the query to be made. I do not know how to pass them to the `bind_param` function, because it only accepts the binding parameters as single variables.

Is it possible to convert dynamically the `param` array to variables which then can be passed to `bind_param`?

Furthermore I am wondering how to bind the results best, as I don't know how many results are going to be returned. Actually it is the same problem as above.

Comment: can't you call `bind_param` in a loop, once for each variable (with `$param_string[i], $param[i]` as parameters for example...) ?

Comment: Are you talking something like [variable length args](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)?

Comment: Or potentially something more like [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)?

Comment: You can only loop over bind_param if you execute the statement in each iteration. This would cause a high overhead.

Comment: Jon, call_user_func_array seems tempting, but I guess you cannot pass a fixed string as the first paramter and convert the array to the 2nd, 3th,... parameter?!

Comment: @null You should be able to merge them into a single array. E.g. you could always `array_unshift` the string onto the beginning of the params array and pass that in.

Comment: A loop is only going to be an overhead if you're doing this thousands of times per request, otherwise it's by far the easiest, most efficient and most readable method.... and using something like `array_walk()` is probably going to be more efficient than a `foreach()` loop

Comment: Jon, your proposal to use "call_user_func_array" works like a charm. See my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Jon's proposal to use `call_user_func_array` I managed to get the following solution:

```
private function prepared_statement($query, $params, $param_string) {

        $fetched_data = array();
        $binding_params[] = & $param_string;

        foreach($params as &$current_param) {
            $binding_params[] = & $current_param;
        }

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        if (!$stmt) {
            //TODO log
            echo "Error in prepared statement";
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $binding_params);
        $stmt->execute();   
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            foreach($row as $r) 
                array_push($fetched_data, $r);

        }

        $stmt->close(); 
        return $fetched_data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a array like this:

```
$array = Array("name"=>"Jhon","surname"=>"Conor");
```

you can do:

```
extract($array);
```

and then use like this:

```
echo "Your name is " . $name . " and your surname is " . $surname;
```

Comment: This approach only works if I knew how many binding parameters exist. As each query look differently I cannot foresee the size of '$array'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '$' twice to get the variable:

```
foreach($my_arr AS $k => $v){
    $$k = $v;
}
```